# Write Recurrence for Given Function

Tags: recurrence

I am trying to write the recurrence relation for the running time of the following function:

```
function G(n):
    if n>0 then:
        x=0
        for i = 1 to n:
            x = x + 1
         G(n-1)
    end if
```

What I came up with was:

```
 T(n) = 1 if n <= 0
 T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 if n>0
```

However I was told that this was incorrect and I don't know why or what the correct solution would be. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The definition of G(n) you've written doesn't make much sense.  Is this supposed to be a particular language or pseudocode?  In most programming languages the call to G(n-1) would simply throw its result away, and there's no code path dealing with negative inputs which in various languages can mean you'll get zero, or some number that just happened to be in memory, or a compile error.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury yeah I am just as confused as you are. That is just how the function is given to me. I was told by someone that instead of doing +1 that it should be switched to +O(n) and that it had something to do with the for loop but I wasn't sure why

Comment: Oh, so maybe they're not asking for a recurrence for G itself, but rather for its *runtime*, and they just put the extraneous call to G in there to waste time?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury The problem just says "Write a recursive relation T(n) to describe th running time of function G"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T(n) = 1 if n <= 0
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n) if n>0
```

Instead of `O(1)`, it should be `O(n)`, because you are looping from 1 to `n`

If you solve the recurrence, the overall complexity will be O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Okay so it would be O(n) because +1 would mean I am just like adding a single value or something but since I am looping it's O(n)?

Comment: Exactly, read basic asymptotic notations and run-time complexities of common algorithms, you will understand how this works.

Comment: Okay and could you explain why it would be O(n^2) total time. It would make n calls up until n was <=0 and then each call would take O(n) time because of the +O(n) so then that gives a O(n^2) total?

Comment: Your are almost correct, that's a quick way to think about it, and yes it worked here. This way we may end up getting loose upper bounds. But, in order to get tighter upper bounds, solving the recurrence is a better option.